# background img size and positioning different when viewed on actual phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools, background-image

The background img of my mobile site changes size and positioning when it is viewed on my actual iphone (safari/google chrome). In google chrome dev tools it is exactly how I want it because I've been using dev tools to position everything.

The background is one large img file which I wanted to display a portion of on mobile and then be responsive on larger devices. I've viewed my site on quirktools and it is displays the way I want it to however, once again when I view it on my phone no dice...

This is how I want the background img to be displayed on mobile devices:

[display on google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMoB2.jpg)

This is what is looks like instead:

[display on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhH9r.jpg)

my website is: [website](http://steppinstonemusic.com)

I have a link to the jsfiddle as well: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drsolow/wx17kz62/29/)

```
body {
       overflow-x: hidden;
       background-image: url("../img/aboutBG.png");
       background-position:95%;
       background-size:cover;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       font-family: felt-tip-senior;
     }
```

If anyone could help me out that would be awesome.

Thanks again,

kaldur'ahm

Comment: The background image in your fiddle is broken, which makes this problem hard to debug. Could you update the fiddle?

Comment: I've fixed the jsfiddle but, it's messing with the formatting I have originally. So, if you could refer to my actual site aswell. Thanks for helping me out